# How to change the 'transform' attribute in svg directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an html code with svg embedded like this:

```
<svg id="mysvg" ...
    <rect id="myrect" x="10" y="10" width="90" height="90" ... />
    ...
</svg>
```

In Javascript, I want the rectangle rotate, so I tried (with JQuery):

```
$("#myrect").attr("transform", "rotate(45, 50, 50)");
```

but it doesn't work, even though in the html code, the `transform` attribute is added to the rectangle. I tried the `Element.setAttributeNS()` function but it does not work either.

After some study, I learnt the following approach works:

```
var r = $("#mysvg").get(0).createSVGTransform();
var t = $("#myrect").get(0);
t.transform.baseVal.appendItem(r);
r.setRotate(45, 50, 50);
```

Although it works, it will be much easier if I can change the `transform` attribute directly. I don't know if there is any way to do so (I can change other attribute like `x` and `y` directly using `$().attr()`). By the way, the browser I am using is Chrome.

Comment: @CBroe Have you tried `.prop` yourself? I got `Cannot assign to read only property 'transform' of object` error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Changing transform using attr seems to work here,..

Have you got more of your code you can show?

```js
$('#myrect').attr('transform', 'rotate(10)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mysvg">
    <rect id="myrect" x="10" y="10" width="90" height="90"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, it works for me if I tried the code in the Chrome console, but not if I wrote it in js file and load it.

Comment: I also tried it on FireFox and Edge, either in the console or js file, and they all works. So it seem to be the chrome issue, but I cannot confirm that.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and the above snippet is working for me.  Maybe you have some Chrome extension that's causing issues?.  Or maybe Chrome version?  Also are you doing on DOM ready..